# How to get all the packages that "conflict" with a specific package?

Tags: apt

I know you can get the metadata of a package using "apt-get depends ".
I would like to find all the packages that "Conflict" . Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `apt show …` lists Conflicts, Breaks and Replaces:

This is part of the output I see with `apt show plasma-desktop` in Kubuntu 18.04

```
Recommends: bluedevil, breeze-gtk-theme, fonts-noto, fonts-oxygen, kde-config-gtk-style, kde-config-screenlocker, kde-config-sddm, kde-style-oxygen-qt5, kgamma5, khelpcenter, khotkeys, kinfocenter, kio-extras, kmenuedit, kscreen, ksshaskpass, ksysguard, kwin-x11 | kwin, kwrited, libpam-kwallet5, plasma-discover, plasma-pa, powerdevil, sni-qt, systemsettings, user-manager
Conflicts: kde-workspace-bin, kde-workspace-data, plasma-widget-kimpanel
Breaks: baloo-kf5 (<< 5.5), kactivities (<< 5.21), kde-config-touchpad (<< 4:5), plasma-dataengines-addons (<< 4:5.8.3), plasma-desktop-data (<< 4:5.3.2-0ubuntu1~), plasma-desktop-dev (<< 4:5.0.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.10~ppa8), plasma-widgets-addons (<< 4:5.6.0~), qml-module-org-kde-activities (<< 5.26.0)
Replaces: baloo-kf5 (<< 5.5), kactivities (<< 5.21), kde-config-touchpad (<< 4:5), kde-workspace-bin, kde-workspace-data, plasma-dataengines-addons (<< 4:5.8.3), plasma-desktop-data (<< 4:5.3.2-0ubuntu1~), plasma-desktop-dev (<< 4:5.0.2-0ubuntu1~ubuntu14.10~ppa8), plasma-widget-kimpanel, plasma-widgets-addons (<< 4:5.6.0~), qml-module-org-kde-activities (<< 5.26.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution is to use Aptitude's `why-not` option (see `man aptitude` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html)):

> **`why-not`** finds a dependency chain leading to a conflict with the target
>              package

Below is an example from my 16.04 LTS system:

> ```
> $ aptitude why-not vim:i386
> i   vim Conflicts vim:i386
> ```